# zlibWEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3.createDeflate is not a function while renderin react-pdf component

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf, react-pdf-viewer

I'm using react pdf to render my component as PDF & allow user to download that PDF on button the PDF was working well after applying pollyfills changes but for my lead (who is using MAC) the PDF was not rendering and giving the

```
Error: react_devtools_backend.js:4026 TypeError: zlibWEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3.createDeflate is not a function
```

On deployment it's even works well on his system but locally he can't render it, does anyone have idea what issue that would which causing this things?

I tried to clone the repo in another folder & installed all the dependencies again but nothing works yet

Here's the screenshot of console error: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/990645691531534370/1012846396296138833/Screen_Shot_2022-08-26_at_3.09.51_PM.png

I found the similar issue opened as well source: https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1935
But it's closed without any proper explanation